# How to prevent jQuery code from too much nesting functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know if calling this *nesting* is correct or not? But I know it's not a good code to have many function inside each others. Most of the jQuery methods have callback function that we can put our callbacks in there. But when we do callbacks inside another callback and continue this and going deeper and deeper it seems code become less readable and maybe less debuggable.

For example if I want to do some animations after each other I have to call every animation that I want to come after another one in it's callback function. It will go deeper and deeper in callback function. Look at this example([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen/TbkjK/)):

```
$('#t').animate({height: 400}, 500, function(){
    $(this).animate({height: 200}, 500, function(){
        $(this).animate({width: 300}, 500, function(){
            $(this).animate({height: 300}, 500, function(){
                $(this).animate({'border-radius': '50px'}, 500, function(){
                    //and so on...
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

for doing a 5 steps animation I have to make a 5 level call stack. So my question is how you avoid this? I had same problem in my Node.js functions too.

**Update:**
I know jQuery function have chinning feature but that don't solve the problem. because you can't do something in between of the chain. You could write above code like `$(selector').animate().animate()...` but you can't do same for this:

```
$('#t').animate({height: 400}, 500, function(){
        console.log('step 1 done: like a boss');
        $(this).animate({height: 200}, 500, function(){
            console.log('step 2 done: like a boss');
            $(this).animate({width: 300}, 500, function(){
                console.log('step 3 done: like a boss');
                $(this).animate({height: 300}, 500, function(){
                    console.log('step 4 done: like a boss');
                    $(this).animate({'border-radius': '50px'}, 500, function(){
                        //and so on...
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

The ideal solution would be a code like this:

```
$(selector).doQ(anim1, anim2, myfunc1, anim3, myfunc2)...
```

But sadly jQuery don't have an API like this(to my knowledge).

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with nesting functions like that.

Comment: @Nathan: Really? Try debugging, maintaining, and reading code that is nested that deep.

Comment: @Andrew I mean I think it will work. I thought he was asking if it is proper or not. And yes, it's very hard to debug, read, and maintain.

Comment: jCeption. We must callback deeper... Ok I'm done.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> *"The ideal solution would be a code like this:
>
> $(selector).doQ(anim1, anim2, myfunc1, anim3, myfunc2)..."*

This isn't quite what you want, but jQuery does have the [`queue()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) method:

```
$(selector).animate({height: 400}, 500)
           .animate({height: 200}, 500)
           .queue( myfunc1 )
           .animate({width: 300}, 500)
           .queue( myfunc2 );
```

You just need to make sure that your functions release the queue when they're done by using the [`dequeue()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) method:

```
function myfunc1() {
    // your code
    $(this).dequeue();
}
```

Or you can wrap your functions in an anonymous function, and invoke then dequeue there:

```
$(selector).animate({height: 400}, 500)
           .animate({height: 200}, 500)
           .queue( function( nxt ) {
               myfunc1();
               $(this).dequeue();
            })
           .animate({width: 300}, 500)
           .queue( function( nxt ) {
               myfunc2();
               nxt(); // alternate way to dequeue
            });
```

Comment: this, but myfunc1 must take an argument `next` and run `next();` when it's done or it won't continue.

Comment: Ha, I just wrote that too ;) +1

Comment: @evan: See my updates, though you can use `.dequeue()` instead of the argument passed.

Comment: @patrick, as always your answer is perfect and detailed and awesome! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Read up on jQuery queues. Your code could also be written like this:

```
$('#t')
    .animate({height: 400}, 500)
    .animate({height: 200}, 500)
    .animate({width: 300}, 500)
    .animate({height: 300}, 500)
    .animate({'border-radius': '50px'}, 500);
```

The first animation is run immediately, but the others are put on the "fx" queue and executed in turn when the others finish.

Comment: `$('#t').animate({height: 400}, 500, function () {/* ... */}).animate({height: 200}, 500, function () {/* ... */});` etc

Answer (score 4):

Read up on JQuery's [Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

> It is a chainable utility object that can register multiple callbacks
>   into callback queues, invoke callback queues, and relay the success or
>   failure state of any synchronous or asynchronous function.

If your callbacks are ONLY animation, then just chain them and utilize JQuery's fx queue.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery objects have a default queue. Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TbkjK/1/

Comment: What if you want to do something in between? Look at my updated question

Comment: That was never part of the question... However, you could chain the animations, have a callback when you want to do something extra, then finish the chain in the callback.

Answer (score 2):

A little cleaner way:

```
$('#t')
    .animate({height: 400}, 500, animationDone)
    .animate({height: 200}, 500, animationDone)
    .animate({width : 200}, 500, animationDone)
    .animate({height: 300}, 500, animationDone)
    .animate({'border-radius': '50px'}, 500, animationDone);


var logCount = 0;
function animationDone(e) {
    logCount++;

    $("#t").html("Animation # " + logCount + " has completed!");
}
```

Simply do something based on the `logCount` number. Example can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TbkjK/4/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't wanted a case based solution. I just add the example for better understanding of question

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is define functions with a name, and reference them inside another function, for example

```
  var clicka = function(){
    alert("I got clicked after t.")
  }
  var clickt = function(){
        alert("I got clicked!")
        $('#a').click(clicka)
  }
  $('#t').click(clickt);
```